# XEN - Does pygrub alter grub on dom0

Tags: xen, grub, grub2

I apologize for question but I did not really understand the idea behind pygrub. I've downloaded VM from stacklet.com. The image is shipped as a ext4 file and pygrub config. My question is if I can run this image from dom0 standard way: `xl create -f debian.7-8.x86.20150217.pygrub.cfg -c` without being worry that pygrub will overwrite or somehow modify my current grub2 config on dom0?

```
file debian.7-8.x86.20150217.img 
(10:42:14 PM) wakatana: debian.7-8.x86.20150217.img: Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data, UUID=39c0e071-393f-4ba3-8aea-51072590991f, volume name "root" (extents) (large files) (huge files)


cat debian.7-8.x86.20150217.pygrub.cfg
bootloader = "/usr/bin/pygrub"
memory = 512
name = "debian.7-8.x86.20150217"
vif = [ '' ]
disk = ['file:/var/stacklet/debian.7-8.x86.20150217.img,xvda,w']
root = "/dev/xvda"
extra = "fastboot"
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, pygrub does not alter the dom0 grub, all credits goes to PryMar56 from #xen channel on freenode. As I understand correct then pygrub is tool that can extract the boot loader from given image and start that image, so there is no need to specify bootloader or kernel/ramdisk. The image must be of course prepared for this e.g. [www.stacklet.com](http://www.stacklet.com) offers those images. One could also check if pygrub is able to extract bootloader by using `pygrub -q imagename` in some cases it needs temporary space so this should do the trick `mkdir -p /var/run/xend/boot/`